# XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: angularjs, spring

http://here ip address :8080/hospital/user/profile
this is my server link which provides a data but is fails to get data in my angular controller console gets the following error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ip address of server:8080/hospital/user/profile. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

ctrl.$inject = ['$location','$scope', '$http', '$rootScope'];

```
function ctrl($location,$scope, $http, $rootScope){




    $scope.reg = function(){
        alert("in the function");
        $http.get('http://ipaddr:8080/hospital/user/profile').success(function(response) {   
          $scope.data = response.data; 
        alert("in the function data is"+response);
          console.log(response);
        }).error(function(response){     
        alert(" Fail to Access Data"); 
        });

    };
```

Comment: set header to allow cors when you send response from api

Comment: Cors Issue: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CORS filter in your Server
plz check http://enable-cors.org/server.html to configure your server

Comment: hey !!!!!!!!!!! thank you so much i added CORS to my chrome browser and it works successfully                                                                                                                   Thank you

Comment: @sush plz accept as answer if it solves ur purpose ! cheers !!